# UITableView with toolbar and multiple segues

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a simple storyboard file with a table view inside a navigation controller. If you cick one of the cells it goes to the details view. Great.

Then I tried adding a toolbar button and hooking it up to my table view controller. The button and the seque seems to work fine, except now, when i click on one of the table cells, the modal view is triggered.

So it seems I have done something wrong, but I don't  understand what.

[image]

```
// called by pressing the add button in the toolbar
- (IBAction)showAddEventView:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAddEvent" sender:sender];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showAddEvent"]) {
        AddEventVC *addEventVC = [[AddEventVC alloc] init];
        // set some property
    } else {
        EventIndexVC *eventIndexVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        eventIndexVC.eventTitle = [self.events objectAtIndex: [[self.tableView     indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a picture of your storyboard?

Comment: Are you performing the segues programmatically via `performSegueWithIdentifier` or is it triggered by the Storyboard? If the latter, then you might've accidentally connected the modal segue to the table view, rather than the controller.

Comment: My bad! I had mixed up the name of the segues in didSelectRowAtIndexPath... Need to step away from the computer and get some rest :)